# Python multiple arguments issue

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm currently facing an issue with my write line in my script:

```
out_file.write(",".join(CX, SDX, EDX, NCX, CJX, LX, POIX, DOIX, NAAX, DOGX, NKX) + "\n")
```

The error I get is

```
TypeError: str.join() takes exactly one argument (11 given)
```

I understand I need to only give one argument, however I can't quite seem to work out how to condense them to fit my 11 headings with this approach.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Edit:

```
Full code:
import re
import csv
import os

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

path = r'D:/E/F/Test1'

ext = '.htm'

out_file = open('names.csv', 'w')
out_file.write(",".join(['Ref', 'Start date of Validity', 'country', 'End date of validity', 'Nomenclature code', 'Classification justification', 'Language', 'Place of issue', 'Date of issue', 'Name and address', 'Description', 'keywords']) + "\n") # Write your keys

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    
    if filename.endswith(ext):

        
        fullpath = os.path.join(path, filename)

        filename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(filename))[0]

        soup = BeautifulSoup(open(fullpath, encoding="utf-8"), 'html.parser')

        text = soup.get_text()

        ref = soup.find("td", text="Reference")
        pattern = re.compile(r'GBBTI\S{9}')
        IC = soup.find("b", text="Issuing country")
        CX = IC.findNext("td").contents
        SD = soup.find("b", text="Start date of validity")
        SDX = SD.findNext("td").contents 
        ED = soup.find("b", text="End date of validity")           
        EDX = ED.findNext("td").content
        NC = soup.find("b", text="Nomenclature code")
        NCX = NC.findNext("td").contents        
        CJ = soup.find("b", text="Classification justification")
        CJX = CJ.findNext("td").contents        
        L = soup.find("b", text="Language")
        LX = L.findNext("td").contents        
        POI = soup.find("b", text="Place of issue")
        POIX = POI.findNext("td").contents
        DOI = soup.find("b", text="Date of issue")
        DOIX = DOI.findNext("td").contents
        NAA = soup.find("b", text="Name and adress")
        NAAX = NAA.findNext("td").contents
        DOG = soup.find("b", text="Description of goods")
        DOGX = DOG.findNext("td").contents
        NK = soup.find("b", text="National keywords")
        NKX = NK.findNext("td").contents


        out_file.write(",".join((CX, SDX, EDX, NCX, CJX, LX, POIX, DOIX, NAAX, DOGX, NKX)) + "\n")
out_file.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to combine the arguments into a list or a tuple by adding a set of `[]` or `()` around them:

```
out_file.write(",".join((CX, SDX, EDX, NCX, CJX, LX, POIX, DOIX, NAAX, DOGX, NKX)) + "\n")
```

PS: You might also consider using [the `csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html); you'll still need the double brackets, but it'll automatically handle the `,` and `\n` for you as well as various other things

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
They are indeed variable names unfortunately

Comment: Depending on what's in them, you might want to put them in a list or a dictionary; that depends on whether they're all undergoing the same kind of processing or whether they are indeed entirely separate values that only really need to come together here

Comment: BTW, you might also consider using [the `csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html); you'll still need the double brackets, but it'll automatically handle the `,` and `\n` for you as well as various other things

Comment: Yeah, that should definitely be in a loop, since you do exactly the same operations for each of the fields. At the top of the code you'd have a `FIELDS = ["Issuing country", "Start date of validity", ...]` and then you'd loop through that and extract it into a list or a dict. However, that's a separate question to the `.join()` problem...

Comment: BTW, you don't seem to use the `ref` and `pattern` variables

Answer (score 1):

The `join` method takes a sequence of values, it's not `*args`, it's `args`.

So you should use `join` like this:

```
out_file.write(",".join((CX, SDX, EDX, NCX, CJX, LX, POIX, DOIX, NAAX, DOGX, NKX)) + "\n")
```

Or without `join`:

```
out_file.write(CX + "," + SDX + "," + EDX + "," + NCX + "," + CJX + "," + LX + "," + POIX + "," + DOIX + "," + NAAX + "," + DOGX + "," + NKX + '\n')
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks like I may be better not using join

Answer (score 0):

The `.join()` method takes an iterable as an input, meaning it just takes one argument that it can iterate over. This could be a list, tuple - any python iterable which you then pass in as a single arugment.

You could easily achieve this in your code by converting the items you're passing in individually into a list that contains **all** of those items:

`out_file.write(",".join([CX, SDX, EDX, NCX, CJX, LX, POIX, DOIX, NAAX, DOGX, NKX])+ "\n")`

Comment: Mismatched brackets, BTW